# App slower on real device than in Emulator

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, opengl-es, android-emulator

I programmed an OpenGL android game.

When I run it on my device (OnePlus One) it's way more laggy than when I run it on the Anroid Studio Android Emulator.

This makes no sense to me. A real device should be far more fast at rendering and have a better performance than the Emulator, due to the fact,  that I have a relatively midrange laptop. (Intel i7-4500U, dual core with up to 2.7 GHz, 8GB RAM, Geforce GT 750m)

Anyone got an explanation for this?

Comment: We can't explain it, without any code to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design the new Android Emulator is actually faster in most cases than a physical Android device. See my talk on this from the Android Developer Summit, where we launched the new Android Emulator. https://youtu.be/fs0eira2pRY?t=27m42s

OpenGL ES graphics is specifically faster than most Android physical devices because if you used the default configuration when you setup your AVD, we directly utilize the host GPU on your laptop to render OpenGL ES instructions from your Android app. Even GPU card on a mid-tier laptop is somewhat slower than an Android phone GPU.